# Erro ao executar a aplicação em outro computador

Tags: delphi, aplicação-desktop

Desenvolvi uma aplicação que na hora de executar em meu computador a mesma executa normalmente porém ao tentar executar a mesma aplicação em outro equipamento o seguinte erro aparece e não consigo acessar o Banco de Dados:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: Já copiei todas as dll's que estão junto do meu projeto para o computador, também copiei os arquivo dbxconnections.ini e o dbxdrivers.ini porém o erro persiste, se tiverem alguma ideia

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão do PostgreSQL é 9.6.0

E o conteúdo do DBXConnection é:

```
[Devart PostgreSQL]     
BlobSize=-1                     
HostName=192.168.1.130                          
DataBase=BancoDados                          
SchemaName=                               
DriverName=DevartPostgreSQL                            
User_Name=postgres                      
Password=masterkey                         
FetchAll=True                   
UseQuoteChar=False                        
EnableBCD=True                     
ServerCharSet=
```

Configuração DBDrivers:

```
[Devart PostgreSQL]                                    
GetDriverFunc=getSQLDriverPostgreSQL                         
LibraryName=dbexppgsql.dll                  
VendorLib=dbexppgsql.dll                  
Database=BancoDados                 
User_Name=postgres                
Password=masterkey                  
ServerCharSet=                         
BlobSize=-1                    

[AutoCommit]                    
False=0                    
True=1

[BlockingMode]                     
False=0                  
True=1

[WaitOnLocks]                       
False=1                           
True=0

[CommitRetain]                              
False=0                        
True=1

[OS Authentication]                              
False=0                          
True=1

[Multiple Transaction]                         
False=0                          
True=1

[Trim Char]                            
False=0                            
True=1

[DB2 TransIsolation]                                
DirtyRead=0                           
ReadCommited=1                              
RepeatableRead=2

[Interbase TransIsolation]                                         
ReadCommited=1                           
RepeatableRead=2

[Oracle TransIsolation]                       
DirtyRead=0                       
ReadCommited=1                                           
RepeatableRead=2

[Informix TransIsolation]                            
DirtyRead=0                          
ReadCommited=1                              
RepeatableRead=2

[MSSQL TransIsolation]                               
DirtyRead=0                 
ReadCommited=1                             
RepeatableRead=2

[SQLDialect]                                        
1=0                                  
2=1                                                
3=2
```

Código:

```
procedure TdmDatabase.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SQLConnection.Connected := false;
  SQLConnection.LoadParamsOnConnect := true;
  SQLConnection.AutoClone := false;
  SQLConnection.LoginPrompt := false;
  SQLConnection.LoadParamsFromIniFile('dbxconnections.ini');
  //SQLConnection.LoadParamsFromIniFile('LOCAL_dbxconnections.ini');
  SQLConnection.Connected := true;
end;
```

Comment: O `SQLConnection` está desabilitado, sendo que o mesmo só será habilitado na hora de abrir o sistema, configurando o banco corretamente? Ou talvez você esqueceu o componente conectado, gerando o erro...

Comment: @Andrey É o SQL connection abriria apenas dentro da aplicação, nesse caso eu teria que abri-lo desde o inicio sozinho?

Comment: Acho que meu comentário ficou meio confuso mesmo, o certo é só conecta-lo ao abrir a aplicação.  
Dê uma olhada nesse [link](http://forum.devmedia.com.br/viewtopic.php?t=50217)

Comment: @Andrey pois é eu tentei fazer o que o link sugeriu porém o erro persistiu

Comment: O banco é `FireBird`? O mesmo está instalado na máquina? Talvez seja necessário copiar o `FBClient.dll`

Comment: O banco é PostgreSQL, e o banco só esta instalado na minha máquina, dai quando tento abrir a aplicação em outra maquina a mensagem de erro ocorre, na minha máquina o erro não ocorre

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48747/discussion-between-andrey-and-r-santos).

Comment: @Andrey Eu identifico o banco no componente sql connection onde coloco o IP de onde o banco esta instalado, isso seria o suficiente certo?

Comment: Se possível, poderia por favor postar a rotina de conexão com o banco, e o conteúdo do dbxconnection. E também  informar qual versão do Postgresql você está utilizando ?

Comment: @VictorZanella eu editei a pergunta com as informações que requisitou

Comment: @VictorZanella Coloquei também como esta configurado o DBXDrivers, acredito que esse também tenha importância

Comment: Poste por favor a parte do código de sua aplicação onde você conecta o componente ao banco. Ex.: `SQLConnection.Connected := True`.  
Poste todo o bloco onde você faz a operação acima.

Comment: @Andrey Editei a pergunta com a parte que você pediu

Comment: Estranho você não ter colocado a porta, e ter funcionado. Já tentou colocar a porta padrão no Host? Ex.: HostName=192.168.1.130:5432

Comment: Isso seria apenas no DBXConnection.ini @VictorZanella? Pois eu editei o arquivo apenas porém o erro persiste em outro computador, nome funcionou normalmente

Comment: não posso te dizer con certeza. porque voce implementa os parametros em tempo de Design, em tempo de Execução e pelo DBXConnection. Você deveria usar somente uma delas. Para o teste, coloque em DesignTime e no DbxConnection

Comment: @VictorZanella eu editei nos lugares que tu comentou e o erro passou a ser: `dbExpress Error: Invalid Username/password` Isso quando tento acessar em outro computador

Comment: Me parece (não tenho certeza) que seu usuário e senha são os padrões do postgresql. Sugiro que muda isso quanto antes. Para continuar os testes, tira o Username e password do DbxConnetion e do componente SQLConnection. Se não der certo, tenta mudar o usuario e senha do banco, e coloque apenas no código. Senha de Banco nunca pode ficar em um arquivo aberto como o dbxconnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver o erro após o auxilio dos comentários e também através da ajuda do usuário @Sorack, resumindo precisei alterar as configurações do arquivo `pg_hba.conf` e adicionar uma regra de entrada no Firewall para a porta 5432, assim consegui acessar a aplicação de outros computadores

Alteração do arquivo pg_hba.conf:

Adicionei a seguinte linha:
**host  all         all     0.0.0.0/0       trust**

Comment: só não esquece de tirar a senha do banco do dbxconnection. :D

Comment: @VictorZanella Ah ta certo, obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Notei que a propriedade `LoadParamsOnConnect` está `true` no seu código. Remova a linha que atribui o valor a propriedade e altere no componente para `false`:

```
  SQLConnection.LoadParamsOnConnect := false;
```

Certifique-se também que o arquivo `dbExpint.dll` está na sua aplicação e que o componente `midas` está registrado.